# Что такое директива мультиветвления препроцессора?

Tags: c

Что такое **директива мультиветвления** препроцессора?
Что требуется сделать? 
Из задания:

> Разработать несколько вариантов программы с использованием директив препроцессора:
>
> При тестировании программы продемонстрировать работу всех вариантов без удаления кода соответствующего варианта с помощью директивы мультиветвления препроцессора.

Про директивы знаю, но **директива мультиветвления**
сбивает с толку.

Comment: Тоже впервые слышу о такой, хотя пишу на Си года с 86-го

Comment: Первый раз слышу. Может имеется в виду ветвление с несколькими ветвями: `#if #else #endif` или `#if #elif #else #endif`, в противоположность `#if #endif`?

Comment: Судя по природе задания, именно это и имеется в виду. `#if #elif #elif ... #endif`.

Comment: Спасибо. Оформите ответ пожалуйста.

Comment: Это обычно называется не "мультиветвление", а *условная компиляция* (conditional compilation)

Comment: Спасибо. Дайте кто-нибудь ответ )  Ответ AnT подходит.